# Nuxt.js + Bootstrap-Vue - Individual components and directives loading

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm working on integrating Bootstrap-Vue library into my Nuxt.js based project. I read through [official documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs) to get started but although importing bt-vue as a single module works fine, I would like to be able to import individual components and directives to reduce resulting file size and make my setup as afficient as possible. Documentation only provides a solution for a regular Vue.js project on this topic, but how can I write a plugin that would enable me to do the same with Nuxt?

I started with creating a `bt-vue.ts` plugin like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Card } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';

Vue.use(Card);
```

I've imported this file into nuxt.config.js plugins section

```
plugins: [
...
'@/plugins/bt-vue'
...
]
```

but when I try to compile my project I recieve this error:

```
node_modules\bootstrap-vue\es\components\index.js:1
  (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Alert from './alert';
  ^^^^^^

  SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
  at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
  at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
  at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
  at r (C:\Projects\Wonder\frontend-nuxt\node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.js:8330:16)
  at Object.bootstrap-vue/es/components (server-bundle.js:5771:18)
  at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
  at Module../plugins/bt-vue/index.ts (plugins/bt-vue/index.ts:1:0)
  at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
  at Module../.nuxt/index.js (.nuxt/index.js:1:0)
  at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
```

Comment: Can you try this solution from clarcdo: adding dom-classes to externals ----  

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isServer) {
        config.externals = [
          nodeExternals({
            whitelist: [/^dom-classes/]
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: What is dom-classes? Should I create a separate module for this? Is it possible to use with Webpack 4? Maybe I can use extendBuild function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 2.0.0-rc.14 using BootstrapVue with Nuxt got greatly simplified due to introduction of built in Nuxt module that eliminates the need to create a plugin by hand.
In order to get the same result as above you just need to register a bt-vue module as well as some special settings inside nuxt.config.js:

```js
modules: ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt'],
bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false, // here you can disable automatic bootstrapCSS in case you are loading it yourself using sass
    bootstrapVueCSS: false, // CSS that is specific to bootstrapVue components can also be disabled. That way you won't load css for modules that you don't use
    componentPlugins: ['Collapse', 'Dropdown'], // Here you can specify which components you want to load and use
    directivePlugins: [] // Here you can specify which directives you want to load and use. Look into official docs to get a list of what's available
  }
```

And in case you are curious about how scss for specific bt-vue components can be loaded:

```scss
@import "~bootstrap-vue/src/variables";
// All bt-vue styles can be imported with this reference
//@import "~bootstrap-vue/src/components/index";

// Importing only styles for components we currently use
@import "~bootstrap-vue/src/components/dropdown/index";
```

Comment: The latest BootstrapVue nuxt plugin now allows importing of individual components and directives.

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of research and some fixes to bt-vue lib I've found a solution to this challenge.
This solution is intended for **Nuxt 2** and **won't work** with Nuxt 1:
First you will need to create a plugin:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Collapse from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/collapse'
import Dropdown from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/dropdown'

Vue.use(Collapse)
Vue.use(Dropdown)
```

We will import only those components that we want to use. More info on that can be found in bt-vue docs under **Component groups and Directives as Vue plugins**

**WARNING:** I suggest to stay away from such import syntax:

`import { Modal } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';`

since it will import everything inside `components` directive anyway and pollute your final bundle with additional JS code since it won't be tree-shaked properly(webpack bug) and this can brake the whole purpose of such setup, so use explicit imports as stated above.

then connect it in nuxt.config.js:

```js
export default {
  build: {
    transpile: ['bootstrap-vue']
  },
  plugins: ['@/plugins/bt-vue']
}
```

As you can see there is no need to include a module since we are writing a plugin ourselves thus no problems with SSR! And we are using new Nuxt 2 `transpile` property to build our es6 bt-vue modules. Don't forget to include a reference to css since it comes separately. In my setup I just import SASS files from regular bootstrap package directly in my index.scss file and include it inside nuxt.config.js as usual.

```js
css: [
    '@/assets/scss/index.scss'
  ]
```

Comment: Small reminder that you need `import Vue from 'vue'` at the start of the plugin import

Comment: It's there, isn't it?